# Spring boot starter mail running indefinitely when sending email

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to send emails from spring boot using spring-boot-starter-mail using a REST api.

After sending a post request with the following body, I never get a response.

```
{
    "senderName":"radwan",
    "confirmationEmail":"email@gmail.com",
    "confirmationBody" : "test body"
}
```

This is the email model :

```
    public class ConfirmationEmail {

    @NotNull
    private String senderName;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String confirmationEmail;

    @NotNull
    private String confirmationBody;

    public String getSenderName() {
        return senderName;
    }

    public void setSenderName(String name) {
        this.senderName = name;
    }

    public String getConfirmationEmail() {
        return confirmationEmail;
    }

    public void setConfirmationEmail(String confirmationEmail) {
        this.confirmationEmail = confirmationEmail;
    }

    public String getConfirmationBody() {
        return confirmationBody;
    }

    public void setConfirmationBody(String confirmationBody) {
        this.confirmationBody = confirmationBody;
    }
}
```

The email configuration class :

```
@Component
public class EmailConfig {

    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and the rest controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/email")
public class EmailController {

    private EmailConfig emailConfig;

    @Autowired
    public EmailController(EmailConfig emailConfig) {
        this.emailConfig = emailConfig;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void sendEmail(@RequestBody ConfirmationEmail confirmationEmail,
                          BindingResult bindingResult) throws ValidationException {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new ValidationException("Invalid");
        }
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        mailSender.setHost(emailConfig.getHost());
        mailSender.setPort(emailConfig.getPort());
        mailSender.setUsername(emailConfig.getUsername());
        mailSender.setPassword(emailConfig.getPassword());


        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        simpleMailMessage.setFrom(confirmationEmail.getConfirmationEmail());
        simpleMailMessage.setTo("mail@gmail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Test Subject from " + 
    confirmationEmail.getSenderName());
        simpleMailMessage.setText(confirmationEmail.getConfirmationBody());


        mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);

    }
}
```

These are the application.properties entries:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.mailtrap.io
spring.mail.port=2525
spring.mail.username=<>
spring.mail.password=<>

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Thanks

EDIT : Added pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mailingTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mailingTest</name>
    <description>mailingTest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is exactely the issue here?

Comment: hi radwan, welcome to stackoverflow! you should try to narrow down your problem first by using dummy smtp server (such as FakeSMTP).

Comment: `@PostMapping public void sendEmail(@RequestBody ConfirmationEmail confirmationEmail, BindingResult bindingResult) throws ValidationException` return `void` so what is you issue ?

Comment: It is a web application, so why shouldn't it keep running? ALso your controller isn't returning anything (it is `void` so nothing, apart from a status 200) will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spring-boot-mail-starter, you do not need to create the sender. That is why some of the properties are not read/in use.

For mailtrap, I believe you should have properties set as such:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.mailtrap.io
spring.mail.port=2525
spring.mail.username=<your username>
spring.mail.password=<your password>
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enabled: true //you are missing this one
```

Then, in your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/email")
public class EmailController {
  private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
  @Autowired
  public EmailController(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
  }
  ...
  @PostMapping
  public void sendEmail(@RequestBody ConfirmationEmail confirmationEmail,
                      BindingResult bindingResult) throws ValidationException {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException("Invalid");
    }
    MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    // set to, from, subject, body/text, etc...
    javaMailSender.send(mail);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see thanks. I've narrowed down my problem to the dependency injection. I am getting Could not autowire. No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found.  I already checked my application.properties files. Any idea of the cause ? Thanks

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml (or gradle file) to see your dependencies and add startup/error log.